# rubygems rest-client error message

Tags: rubygems, rest-client

New Ruby user and I am completely addicted, LOVE it...but...I have hit a roadblock right out of the gate
Have read plenty on the Ruby basics/theory/etc
Working my way through "Bastards" Ruby Lessons and I am getting error message when trying to use "rest-client" gem

I enter:

```
require "rubygems"
require "rest-client"
res = RestClient.get("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki")
puts res.code
#=> 200

puts res.body
#=> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
#=> "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
#=> <html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="client-nojs" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
#=> <head> ...
```

And get:

```
LoadError: no such file to load — rest-client

method gem_original_require in custom_require.rb at line 36
method require  in custom_require.rb at line 36
at top level    in gem.rb at line 2
copy output
Program exited with code #1 after 0.06 seconds.
```

Im sure this is quite basic and feel somewhat embarrassed to ask for help but I have tried every place possible to find a fix

On a Mac OS10

Appreciate your help

Comment: Hmm, you sure it's not `rest_client` with an underscore?  Try changing `require rest-client` to `require rest_client`

Comment: tried that unfortunately it didnt work

Comment: Do `gem install rest-client` then try again

Comment: getting this: NoMethodError: undefined method ‘install’ for main:Object

at top level in gem.rb at line 1
copy output
Program exited with code #1 after 0.03 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer.  In your console I believe you need to install the `rest-client` dependency by first running `gem install rest-client`. It doesn't go in your script, you have to install through the console, then run your script.

Comment: yup, did that but then it gives an error "no such file to load rest-client"

Comment: seems strange, was excited because seemed like ruby and rubygems were properly loaded (finally) but when I try to run a script any script it gets stuck

Comment: In terminal try `gem list` See if `rest-client` is listed.

Comment: bundler (1.2.3)
crack (0.3.1)
mime-types (1.19)
nokogiri (1.5.5)
rake (10.0.2)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rubygems-update (1.8.24)
rvm (1.11.3.5)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do three things:

**1.** In your code change `require 'rest-client'` to `require 'rest_client'`.

**2.** make sure the rest-client gem is installed: at the console, go to your project's directory and type

`$gem list | grep rest-client`

If the gem is installed, the command should return something like *rest-client (1.6.7)*. If that happens, proceed to step #3. If nothing is returned then type:

`$gem install rest-client`

and wait till the gem is installed.

**3.** After the gem has been installed, stay on the same command line and run your script from it. If you're running it from  within an editor, then start your editor from the same command line, e.g.

```
$>sublime-text --project mywork.sublime-project &
```

(assuming sublime-text is in your local bin directory, of course)

Answer (score 0):

answered this
had to cd to proper directory